# Does anyone know how to bcc in R?

Tags: r, bcc

```
library("mailR")
    sender <- "sender@gmail.com"
    bcc<- c("BCC Recipient <bcc1@gmail.com.tr>","BCC Recipient<bcc2@gmail.com.tr>")
    send.mail(from = sender,
              bcc<- c("BCC Recipient <bcc1@gmail.com.tr>","BCC Recipient<bcc2@gmail.com.tr>"),
              subject = "subject",
              body = "BODY
              ",
              authenticate=TRUE,
                smtp = list(host.name = "smtp.gmail.com", port = 465, 
                          user.name = "YOURUSERNAME@gmail.com",            
                          passwd = "YOURPASSWORD", ssl = TRUE),
              send = TRUE,
              attach.files = c("C:/Users/admin/Desktop/Forecast.csv"),
              file.names = c("Demand_Forecast.csv"))
```

Do u know how to send mail with bcc, what is the format?It is working but recipents can see eachother

Answer (score 1):

You have mistakenly used the assignment operator inside the function `send.mail()`.

This should work:

`library("mailR")
    sender <- "sender@gmail.com"
    bcc<- c("BCC Recipient <bcc1@gmail.com.tr>","BCC Recipient<bcc2@gmail.com.tr>")
    send.mail(from = sender,
              bcc = c("BCC Recipient <bcc1@gmail.com.tr>","BCC Recipient<bcc2@gmail.com.tr>"),
              subject = "subject",
              body = "BODY",
              authenticate=TRUE,
                smtp = list(host.name = "smtp.gmail.com", port = 465, 
                          user.name = "YOURUSERNAME@gmail.com",

                          passwd = "YOURPASSWORD", ssl = TRUE),
              send = TRUE,
              attach.files = c("C:/Users/admin/Desktop/Forecast.csv"),
              file.names = c("Demand_Forecast.csv"))`